# What does this mean when interpreted mathematically, rather than this long phrase?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Quoted from: DANIEL A. GOLDSTON, JÁNOS PINTZ, and CEM Y. YILDIRIM, Primes in tuples I, Annals of Mathematics, 170 (2009), 819–862:

> Unconditionally, we prove that there exist consecutive primes which are closer than any arbitrarily small multiple of the average spacing, that is, $$\liminf_{n\to\infty}\frac{p_{n+1}-p_{n}}{\log p_{n}}=0$$

How can we dissect this phrase to interpret it mathematically?

Comment: The $\liminf$ expression is the mathematical interpretation. The rest is verbiage to describe the intuition.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: But this manner of phrasing it is unclear to me.

Comment: What do you mean? I think it is about as clear as it can be

Comment: @Henrik: Unfortunately not for me.

Comment: "But this manner of phrasing it is unclear to me." So? What does that have to do with the meaning of the statement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "expected" gap between $p_{n+1}$ and $p_n$ is $\log p_n$.

The $\liminf$ express means that for any $\epsilon>0$ and $N$ there is an $n>N$ so that:

$$p_{n+1}-p_n < \epsilon \log p_n$$

Which means that we always get examples which are "much smaller" than the expected gap between consecutive primes.

Recent results have shown that $\liminf_{n\to\infty} (p_{n+1}-p_n)<+\infty$, which is a much stronger result. The twin prime conjecture would mean $\liminf (p_{n+1}-p_n)=2$.

Comment: @ Thomas Andrews: This is what I want to see. Good answer.